# how to open or create database by importing sqlite3 in python code

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have python code in which I have imported sqlite3 to open database if it is already present or else create new database in the specified location. When I run the code, it is not displaying any error. I have written testscript , When I try to run the testscript, it is displaying error "'tuple' object does not support item assignment". Can anyone suggest me how can I create the database in sqlite3.

```
import sqlite3
import os


class sqlite1():

    
    def __init__(self, pa, na, rq):

        
        self.dbname = None
        self.name = None
        self.id1 = 0



        if rq == 'open':
          
            print(pa, na)
            self.hdl = (os.path.join(pa, na),'open')
            if not b'id1' in self.hdl or not b'ns' in self.hdl:
                print("open")

            try:
                self.id1 = int(self.hdl[b'id1'])
                self.name = self.hdl[b'ns']
            except:
                pass

        else:
           
            self.hdl = (os.path.join(pa, na),'c')
            self.id1 = 0
            print("File created")

            self.hdl[b'id1'] = str(self.id1)
            




    def getID(self):
        return self.hdl[b'id1']
    def setID(self, id1):
        self.hdl[b'id1'] = id1
```

The testscript is:

```
from sqlite123 import *
from sqlite123 import sqlite1

class Test1:
    def __init__(self, pa, na, rq):
        self.pa = pa
        self.na = na
        self.id1 = 0
        self.abc1 = sqlite1(pa, na, rq)
        self.abc1.setID(0)
        


    def fileopen(self, pa, na, rq):
        self.abc1 = sqlite1(pa, na, rq)
        



if __name__ == '__main__':
   
    tst = Test1('', 'file.db', 'c')
    tst.fileopen('', 'file.db', 'open')
```

Instead of sqlite3 i have imported sqlite3dbm as:

```
import sqlite3dbm
from sqlite3dbm.dbm import *
```

and changed the line:

```
self.hdl = sqlite3dbm.dbm.open(os.path.join(pa, na),'open')
```

the code is working fine but it is displaying keys as 'None' i.e it is not accepting keys.As a result the method getID is not returning the correct value. Any suggestions to resolve it.

Comment: Why did you post the same question again?

Comment: because I didnt get any response to previous question